# Hardhat-Gas-Reporter reports empty with Waffle

Tags: solidity

Problem: Hardhat gas reporter does not display gas reports. The tests are written in Waffle. All tests pass correctly. I want to understand what am I doing wrong and how can I mend this? Here is my `hardhat.congif.js` -

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("hardhat-gas-reporter");

module.exports = {
    gasReporter: {
       enabled: true,
       src: "./src"
}}
```

[image: Hardhat results empty]

Comment: Are you sure your testcases actually run and called your contract's functions? My case was that those testcases were skipped thus gas-reporter reported empty one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this same problem. Later i found i was not giving proper parameters.

I think you should provide at least currency, and an api key (to fetch gas related data). It worked for me.

here is my code:

```
 gasReporter: {
enabled: true,
currency: "USD", // currency to show
outputFile: "gas-report.txt", // optional
noColors: true, //optional
coinmarketcap: process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY, //to fetch gas data
token: "MATIC" // for polygon blockchain(optional).
```

},

Result output:
[image]